# Can the selection of a lookup field be enforced?

Tags: lookup-column

I'm struggling with a lookup column in a list.

For different reasons I need users to choose a value for a new or edited list item in a lookup column. However as far as I can see, there is no possibility to enforce content in a lookup field on creating a new list item. Also lookup colums aren't accessible for column validation formulas, are they?

Of course I can let a Flow check that, but I've got too many flows operating on those lists already so I want to try and do everything what can be done without. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "enforce content" in a lookup field, couldn't you just make that a  **required** field?

Comment: good question. In fact for this column there is no required field knob. That's why I thought, there isn't one for lookup columns at all. I think I have to rephrase my question.

Comment: I'll write a new question with my real problem :)

Comment: Ah, found it out. The column came from a site content type. And it can only be defined there if it is required to hold information.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was wondering... I had never heard of a column not being able to be switched between required/optional, so I was thinking it might be controlled at the content type level.